# SnowSQL How to get all records, including unmatched records from a join using a date range

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Table_Two (T2) contains records with IDs that aren't within Table_One (T1), however, I still want these records.

Furthermore, I'm trying to do this within a date range, which means the IDs present in T2 that aren't present in T1 vary on a day by day basis.

I've tried quite a few queries, and currently I'm attempting:

```
select t1.id
  , t1.date 
  , t1.col1
  , t2.col2
from table_one t1 
join table_two t2 on
  t1.id=t2.id
  and t1.date=t2.date
where date>='2022-11-01' and date<='2022-11-03'
group by t1.id
  , t1.date
union
select t1.id
  , t1.date 
  , t1.col1
  , t2.col2
from table_one t1 
join table_two t2 on
  t1.id=t2.id
  and t1.date=t2.date
where date>='2022-11-01' and date<='2022-11-03'
  t1.id=NULL
group by t1.id
  , t1.date
```

However, the second query is not returning any records.

Am I missing something? I believe this is how I would handle this. Does SnowSQL have a different manner or is this approach just wrong?

Edit - Adding example input and output.

T1:

| id | date | col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-11-02 | 3 |
| 3 | 2022-11-03 | 4 |

T2:

| id | date | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | 6 |
| 3 | 2022-11-01 | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-11-02 | 8 |
| 2 | 2022-11-02 | 9 |
| 1 | 2022-11-03 | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-11-03 | 11 |
| 3 | 2022-11-03 | 12 |

The first query results in:

| id | date | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 2022-11-02 | 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 2022-11-03 | 4 | 12 |

So I'm attempting to grab the following and UNION it:

| id | date | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-11-01 | NULL | 7 |
| 2 | 2022-11-02 | NULL | 9 |
| 1 | 2022-11-03 | NULL | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-11-03 | NULL | 11 |

Full Desired Output (Ordered by date):

| id | date | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-01 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2022-11-01 | 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 2022-11-01 | NULL | 7 |
| 1 | 2022-11-02 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 2022-11-02 | NULL | 9 |
| 1 | 2022-11-03 | NULL | 10 |
| 2 | 2022-11-03 | NULL | 11 |
| 3 | 2022-11-03 | 4 | 12 |

Edit 2 - RESOLVED

So sorry, it was the GROUP BY statement, as it was grouping a NULL ID.

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: Use LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER JOIN to return non-matching data

Comment: @Serg I've tried this to no effect.

Comment: @DGNMW - as you have solved this. Can you mark the question as answered please?